# Let padding of multiple items responsively fit to div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a little table which automaticly reacts to new content.
So basicly what I'm trying is to give the padding of the content in the table not a fixed size 
rather than letting the padding self adjust to fit the table 100%.
Here is an little example for better understanding:

```css
.table{
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FBEFF2;
  position: relative;
}
#cell{
  width: 120px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}
#cell p{
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
.explanation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 180px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div id="cell">
    <p>Adressen</p>
    <p>ALKIS</p>
    <p>Liegenschaften</p>
    <p>Adressen</p>
    <p>ALKIS</p>
    <p>Liegenschaften Big enougth to fit 3 lines</p>
    <p>Adressen</p>
    <p>ALKIS</p>
    <p>Liegenschaften</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="explanation">I want the padding of the "p" elements to automaticly fit to the bottom of #cell. If I would add another "p" element to #cell the padding of all the other "p's" should responsively shrink until all "p" elements <br />fit again...
<br />Possible?
</p>
```

And yes, I want to deal with the padding! I already completed the table but it messes up every time I add new content to the rows.
[image]
So how to fit the padding of the text to the rows automatacly without giving it fixed sizes?

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that

```css
.table {
  width: 180px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FBEFF2;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* for demo */
  vertical-align: top;
  /* for demo */
}
.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 120px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.cell p {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    <p>Adressen</p>
    <p>ALKIS</p>
    <p>Liegenschaften</p>
    <p>Adressen</p>
    <p>ALKIS</p>
    <p>Liegenschaften Big enougth to fit 3 lines</p>
    <p>Adressen</p>
    <p>ALKIS</p>
    <p>Liegenschaften</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    <p>Adressen</p>
    <p>ALKIS</p>
    <p>Liegenschaften</p>
    <p>Adressen</p>
    <p>ALKIS</p>
    <p>Liegenschaften Big enougth to fit 3 lines</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to deal with the margins (space between elements), not the paddings. You could go with `flexbox` , i dropped you a fiddle here (keep in mind you may have to use fallbacks for older browsers with prefixes like `display: -webkit-flex;`)
https://jsfiddle.net/hcoqnagr/

Comment: I want to deal with the padding. I edited my question.